# Unable to save more than 2 property using mongoose in node js REST API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have creating a REST API using Express, Mongoose, and MongoDB,
but it's saving only two property name and email and increase one more property then it's not saving.
below is my model and Router file.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema;

const userModel = new UserSchema({
    sirName: String,
    name: String,
    email: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user',userModel);
```

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const user = require('../models/user');



router.get('/users', (req, res, next)=>{
    res.json({
        'message': 'Fetch All User from Database'
    });
});

//post request

router.post('/user', (req, res)=> {
    const userData = new user({
        sirName: req.body.sirName,
        name : req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email
    })
    userData.save()
    .then(item =>{
        res.send(item)
    })


})

module.exports= router;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @ChukwumaEzumezu : it's saving only name and email not sirName

Comment: Maybe you get problem with camelCase for `sirName` field

Comment: @Valijon: I have changed it sirName to sirname but it did not work.

Comment: Can you show your request object? Also when you log req.body what does it show?

Comment: @ChukwumaEzumezu: I have request using POSTMAN :
```
{
    "sirname": "Mr",
    "name": "Rahul",
    "email": "rahul@email.com"
} 

Response :
{
    "_id": "5e70b03fa193544ed058d7a3",
    "name": "Rahul",
    "email": "rahul@email.com",
    "__v": 0
}

```

Comment: Update to `sirname` in your model

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi : above code is old on as Valijon suggested so i have changed in both files.

Comment: In your request, use sirName. 
Make sure you're using the same entity as per your schema in the request object.


in your case your entity is sirName then in the request object it should be sirName not sirname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema;

const userModel = new UserSchema({
sirName: String,
name: String,
email: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userModel);
```

Your routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const user = require('../model/Users');

router.get('/users', (req, res, next)=>{
res.json({
    'message': 'Fetch All User from Database'
});
});

//post request
router.post('/user', (req, res)=> {
 const userData = new user({
    sirName: req.body.sirName,
    name : req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email
})
userData.save()
.then(item =>{
    res.send(item)
})
})
module.exports= router;
```

And here is your root file

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

const db = require('./setup/keys').my_url

const userRoutes = require('./routes/UserRoutes');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

 mongoose
     .connect(db, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true})
     .then(() => console.log('Connected'))
     .catch(err => console.log(err));

 app.use('/hi', userRoutes);

 app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running at ${port}`))
```

After  Sending JSON Data
[image]

All the data are saved in the databases
[image]

It works fine!!

Comment: Thanks for reply. issue resolved . I was doing wrong, i was writing code in new model but one old model was imported in files.